# Unable to implement the conversion of C# hash code to python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, adb

I am facing issue in converting below C# code to Python , Can anybody help me to How to convert this part of code to Python . Any help will be much appreciated

```
                mLogcatGrabProcess = new Process(); 

                mLogcatGrabProcess.StartInfo.FileName = mADBPath;

                mLogcatGrabProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = logcatcommandargs;

                mLogcatGrabProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                mLogcatGrabProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                mLogcatGrabProcess.OutputDataReceived += LogCatOutputDataHandler;
    
                mLogcatGrabProcess.Start();

                mLogcatGrabProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: `C hash` is not correct. C# is what you meant. Please update your title.

Comment: Please explain why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python does not answer your question.